# How to create/generate fluid water like js animation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, fluid-dynamics

I saw a few examples people are doing background fluid like a water.
For example this websites background: https://spotify-valentines.com/
or this hover effects between divs: http://waaark.com/

It seems to be done on canvas but the code is very minified so its hard to understand what happens.

Is there are some kind of framework for this. If its not how can I call it and where can I read more about it

Thank you!

Comment: There are several ways to display waves. Perhaps adapt this previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229986/onclick-function-button-change-canvas/38237662#38237662) to your needs.